# MDX Member not being filtered

Tags: ssas, mdx

We are trying to develop some MDX Query that allow the user to generate the profit number calculated base on a transaction type. Here is a sample:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Profit] AS 
'((Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[SALE]}, [Measures].[Amount]) + 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[MOTO]}, [Measures].[Amount]) + 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[FORCECAPTURE]}, [Measures].[Amount]) + 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[FORCE]}, [Measures].[Amount]) + 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[RECURRINGSALE2]}, [Measures].[Amount]) + 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[SPECIALFORCE]}, [Measures].[Amount]) + 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[VOICEAUTH]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[VALIDATION]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[REPEATCHECK]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[CONVERSION]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[GENERICCHECK]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[CASHIN]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[CHECKMANUALDEPOSIT]}, [Measures].[Amount]) -
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[RECURRINGCREDIT]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[ACH]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[GUARANTEEANDCHECK2]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[RECURRINGACH]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[GUARANTEE]}, [Measures].[Amount]) +
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[SUPERVISORAPPROVAL]}, [Measures].[Amount])) - 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[RELOAD]}, [Measures].[Amount]) - 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[CASHOUT]}, [Measures].[Amount]) - 
Sum({[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[CREDIT]}, [Measures].[Amount]))' 
SELECT {{[Measures].[Profit],[Measures].[Transaction Number]}} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY {(DESCENDANTS([Location].[All Locations].&[1],1))} ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( -{[Voided].[Voided].[Voided].&[true]},
{[Transaction Response].[TransactionResponses].&[APPROVED]},{[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[SALE],[Transaction Type].[All Transaction Types].[CREDIT]}) ON COLUMNS FROM [DashBoardCube]) 
WHERE  ([Time].[YEAR].&[2012])
```

The issues comes when we try to filter those query using the transaction type, as you can see in the sample above. the Profit value is always the same i assume that is because the definition of the member.

There is a way to archive this based on a calculated member defined as we did ?

Best Regards,

Comment: Question is still not clear, your above MDX should return the SUM of Transaction Types [SALE] and [CREDIT], right?

Comment: Correct, but instead of that it always return the sum of all transactions.

Answer (score 0):

As you note, the definition of the member [Measures].[Profit] is over-riding the filtering of [Transaction Type] in the subcube.  The "addresses" of the tuples that add up to the [Profit] calculated member (e.g. (MOTO, Amount) in shorthand) are resolved against the entire cube, not against the subcube (where, in your example, there is no MOTO member).

This is odd, but it's the way MDX works (in SSAS at least, I don't know about other platforms).

It amounts to a contradiction between the formula of TTypes that make up "Profit" (X+Z+Y-A-B) and the subset of these you specify in the subcube.

I don't know for sure because I can't see your requirements: but doesn't this amount to a real contradiction, rather than just something odd that MDX does?  According to your subcube, you're trying to see SALE-CREDIT.  Isn't this really a new figure, rather than a special type of "Profit"?  Can it really be called "Profit" when it ignores the (-CASHOUT) element?  If ignoring (-CASHOUT) is appropriate in this context, can you guarantee that it always will be across the cube-space, i.e. that this calculation will always make sense?

One solution might to simply explicitly specify (SALE-CREDIT) as the measure you want here, without getting caught up in [Measures].[Profit].

Another might be to give each leaf member of the [Transaction Type] dimension an attribute (Credit or Debit), specifying which side of the Profit calculation it should go on.  A calculated member, something like this (pseudocode)

```
Iif([Transaction Types].IsCreditOrDebit.CurrentMember IS [Transaction Types].IsCreditOrDebit.[Credit],Measures.Amount,-Measures.Amount)
```

could then be aggregated over the entire [Transaction Type] dimension, and would be sliceable by Transaction Type.